# split function on weekdays yields a 1 or 0

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple spreadsheet with meeting names, organizer, days of the week, start time, and length for company meetings. I am using a split function to put the days of the week into an array. I'm certain that column c is the correct column for the days list. But I can't figure out why the split function isn't working correctly. I'll put the class object's code at the bottom. As always any help would be greatly appreciated. Code below.

```
Sub ExportToPPT()

'creates a new object for each BRE day/time combination
count = 0
For Each i In BREitems
    BREdaysString = Split(Cells(i.Row, "c").value, ",")          'This is where the split happens
    For j = 1 To UBound(BREdaysString)

        count = count + 1
        ReDim Preserve BREobjects(count)
        Set BREobjects(count) = New BREpptObjects

        With BREobjects(count)
            .BREname = Cells(i.Row, "a").value
            .BREcategory = Cells(i.Row, "b").value
            .BREdays = BREdaysString(j)                        'this is where the day is assigned to the object's property. This is a 1 or 0 currently. IDK why.
            .BREstartTime = Cells(i.Row, "d").value
            .BRElength = Cells(i.Row, "e").value
            .BREtimeRight = Right(Cells(i.Row, "d").value, 2)
        End With
    Next j
    Erase BREdaysString
Next i

for i = 1 to UBound(BREobjects)
    debug.print BREObjects(i).BREID
next i
.
.
.
'more code that does stuff....
```

Comment: Wilco. I usually get dinged for not providing enough code. lol. Guess I went overboard. Should I keep the object definition? I can definitely get rid of the declarations if we can assume that all variables are declared properly.

Comment: The class code doesn't seem to be relevant to your question... What is the value of `Cells(i.Row, "c")` in `BREdaysString = Split(Cells(i.Row, "c"), ",")`?

Comment: Column C can be any or all of Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, or Sunday. Debug.print shows that the value of BREdaysString is correct on the days of the week

Also, I noticed I didn't have a .value in that split function. Adding it made no difference.

Comment: a debug.print just after assigning BREobjects(count).BREdays shows that it's now a 1 or 0. I have defined BREdays as a string. I don't understand.

Comment: `For j = 1 To UBound(BREdaysString)` - `Split` returns a zero-based array, you should be using `LBound(BREdaysString)` instead of that hard-coded 1.

Comment: That def makes BREdaysString(j) = a day of the week instead of 1 or 0. But BREobjects(count).BREdays still gets set to a number.

Comment: even using For Each j in BREdaysString and assigning is as BREobjects(count).BREdays = j does the same thing. J is a day of the week yet .BREdays is a 1....

Comment: Ok @BigBen, If I pull .BREdays  out of the with block, it sets it correctly. IDK why that works but it does. So wierd, IMO.  Thank you!